# How to use Java optional with int return types?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Below is my code:

```
int sizeOfOjectArray = boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().jsonPath().getList("boards").size();
```

This int value gives me nullPointerException when there are no boards present(in terms of count) in jsonResponse.
To handle this, I used:

```
Optional<Integer> sizeOfOjectArray = Optional.ofNullable(boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().jsonPath().getList("boards").size());
```

My Next operation is to delete those boards which are present:

```
if(sizeOfOjectArray.isPresent()) {
            List <Object> contributorBoardKeyList = new ArrayList <Object>();

            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfOjectArray; i++) {
                contributorBoardKeyList.add(boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().path("boards[" + i + "].boardKey"));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfOjectArray; i++) {
                String boardKey = (String) contributorBoardKeyList.get(i);
                LeaveBoardBaseScript.leaveBoardService(boardKey, deviceContributorInfoTemp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log("There is no Board present.");
        }
```

But after using optional, I am seeing this Java error:

operator ‘<’ can not be applied to ‘int’, `‘java.util.optional<java.lang.integer>’`

What is the best way to handle this error?

Comment: `i < sizeOfOjectArray.get()`?

Comment: The error removed but now, I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException in this line:Optional<Integer> sizeOfOjectArray = Optional.ofNullable(boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().jsonPath().getList("boards").size());

Comment: Well, if `boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().jsonPath().getList("boards")` is null, you would get NPE when calling `size()`.

Comment: Response from where I am expecting sizeOfOjectArray is (this is giving exception):{
    "allocatedSpace": 12859736064,
    "usedSpace": 232641376,
    "lastSyncDate": 1534231948502
}

When board present, the response is:
{
    "allocatedSpace": 18190696448,
    "usedSpace": 1188122011,
    "boards": [
        {
            Board1 data
        },
        {
            Board 2 data
                    }
    "lastSyncDate": 1534231948502
    ],
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use primitive types as Optional.ofNullable expects Objects and another point is the default value of int is 0 which will fail your scenario.

```
Optional<Integer> sizeOfOjectArray = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().jsonPath().getList("boards").size()));
```

This will work in the above given way but better to get list instead of size and use the isEmpty method to check if the list contains an object or not.

> Note: Optional is good to remove null checks in case of size it does
>   not look good and for list also it will be good if getList method can
>   return null.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks. It worked with the suggestion you provided on Note. Below is the code:
List <Object> boardsPresent=boardFeedContributorResponse.extract().jsonPath().getList("boards");
  Optional <List <Object>> opt = Optional.ofNullable(boardsPresent);
  if(opt.isPresent())
  {
   // Do the task

  }
  else{
   log("There is no Board present for Unjoin");
   }

Comment: @deepakmathpal please accept as answer if it's help you.